# Access snippet from Google Search

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm using Google's Custom Search API to get search results from across the web. All I want is to grab the snippets from the results and put them into a list. I'm pretty sure it's a JSON response but I have no idea how to handle this or parse it, and the documentation seems miles over my head. Here's my code so far. How do?

```
import pprint
from apiclient.discovery import build

service = build("customsearch", "v1", 
                developerKey="----------")

res = service.cse().list(
    q='what was the most downloaded android app of 2008',
    cx='-------------my custom engine--------------',
    googlehost='google.com',
    ).execute()

pprint.pprint(res)
```

Comment: There are plenty question on parsing JSON data using python on SO.

Comment: You shouldn't post the `developerKey` value if that's your real one.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer could you point me to one to help? I can't find any that are analogous

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/1777111